# LabelEncoding a permutation of combination of columns

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, permutation, sklearn-pandas

I'd like to create class labels for a permutation of two columns using `sklearn`'s `LabelEncoder()`. How do I achieve the following behavior?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=",")
df
#    A    B    
# 0  1  Yes 
# 1  2   No 
# 2  3  Yes 
# 3  4  Yes
```

I'd like to have the permutation of combination of A && B rather than encoding these two columns separately:

```
df['A'].astype('category')
#Categories (4, int64): [1, 2, 3, 4, ]

df['B'].astype('category')
#Categories (2, object): ['Yes','No']

#Column C should have 4 * 2 classes:
(1,Yes)=1  (1,No)=5
(2,Yes)=2  (2,No)=6
(3,Yes)=3  (3,No)=7
(4,Yes)=4  (4,No)=8

#Newdf
#    A    B  C    
# 0  1  Yes  1
# 1  2   No  6
# 2  3  Yes  3
# 3  4  Yes  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create the mapping df with cross `merge`

```
out = df.merge(df[['B']].drop_duplicates().merge(df['A'].drop_duplicates(),how='cross').assign(C=lambda x : x.index+1))
Out[415]: 
   A    B  C
0  1  Yes  1
1  2   No  6
2  3  Yes  3
3  4  Yes  4
```

More info

```
df[['B']].drop_duplicates().merge(df['A'].drop_duplicates(),how='cross').assign(C=lambda x : x.index+1)
Out[417]: 
     B  A  C
0  Yes  1  1
1  Yes  2  2
2  Yes  3  3
3  Yes  4  4
4   No  1  5
5   No  2  6
6   No  3  7
7   No  4  8
```

Comment: Thanks @BENY. Can we reverse this transformation later for verification? Also, what does df.A mean here?

Comment: @Amir yes you can just keep the mapping df ~ merge it back later on

Comment: would you be able to let me know what does `df.A` refer to? is the the name of column A as 'A'?

Comment: @Amir df.A return a series, which is df['A'] ~

Comment: Cuz if you create `df` using `read_csv` you don't have access to column names with `.`, only newly created columns are there. Could you revise the answer to address this issue?

Comment: I get the following error: `"No common columns to perform merge on. "
pandas.errors.MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False`

Answer (score 1):

You can create additional column merging values from 2 columns into one tuple. But `LabelEncoder` cannot encode the tuples, so additionally you need to get `hash()` of the tuple:

```
df['AB'] = df.apply(lambda row: hash((row['A'], row['B'])), axis=1)
le = LabelEncoder()
df['C'] = le.fit_transform(df['AB'])
```

However, if you want to preserve the exact labels order (that you specified), using `LabelEncoder()` doesn't make sense. You can simply compute the `C` column like that:

```
df['C'] = df['A'] + (df['B']=='No') * df['A'].max()
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   Yes 1
1   2   No  6
2   3   Yes 3
3   4   Yes 4
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to keep the labels for missed combinations (e.g. `(2, 'Yes')`) and need a solution for arbitrary number of classes, you can use 2 `LabelEncoder()`:

```
leA = LabelEncoder()
leB = LabelEncoder()
leA.fit(df['A'])
leB.fit(df['B'])
df['C'] = leA.transform(df['A']) + leA.classes_.size
leB.transform(df['B']) + 1 # if you want labels to start from 1
```

But in this case you cannot preserve the custom order, the list of labels will be automatically sorted, e.g. [1,2,3,4] and ['No','Yes'].

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   Yes 5
1   2   No  2
2   3   Yes 7
3   4   Yes 8
```

Comment: Thanks for an intuitive answer @Boris. Now, `df['C']` has the encoded classes but it reverse order, that is `(Yes,1)` is class 8 rather than 1. How do I reverse the order?

Comment: @Amir: I didn't expect you want to preserve the order. I adjusted the answer.

Comment: Does this extend to the case when Column B has more than 2 classes?

Comment: Also, I wanted to point that the first method is generating only the combination of permutations that are present in the current df. Say, if A didn't have an entry for 4, C would get only 3*2=6 classes and not 8. Is there a way we still generate the full space, regardless of the presence of the combination?

Comment: @Amir: I proposed 2 ways: first - when you don't how many classes you have in total; second - when you know what are your classes and you want to preserve the exact order. `(df['B']=='No')` is actually just a mapping, it can be replaced by `df['B'].map({'Yes': 0, 'No': 1})` and extended. If you want to have a solution for an arbitrary number of classes and preserve the specific order you have to specify how exactly you order the labels. [1, 2, 3, 4] is obviously just an ascending sorting. But how are the column `B` labels ordered? ['Yes', 'No'] and where should we put other values if any?

Comment: Assume we have Column A with 6 unique values and column B with 4: `[a, b, c, d]`. Since we know the unique values for both columns, we expect column df['C'] has 6*4 =24 unique hashed and thus 24 different labels. Chances are, among these 24 classes, we don't have enough data in both columns to represent a specific class (as a result of a combination of permutations), but we still need that class to be labeled anyway and will contain 0 entries. Your solution will only create those labels that are present in the current df & thus, the created classes will be lower than the 24 classes.